# How to Pass Custom arraylist from fragment to activity

Tags: android

**In fragment ---my RecyclerViewAdapter On click**

```
ImageRecycleAdapter.OnImageClicklistener onImageClicklistener=new ImageRecycleAdapter.OnImageClicklistener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClicks(View view, int position) {
        Log.e("onitemclic image",""+position);

          OnimageUrlPass  onimageUrlPass=(OnimageUrlPass)getContext();
            onimageUrlPass.getUrllist(image_final);

            Intent intent=new Intent(getContext(),ImagePagerAct.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    };
```

**Interface in fragment**

```
 public interface OnimageUrlPass{
        void getUrllist(ArrayList<ImageUrl> url);
    }
```

**In Activity Implements**

```
public class ImagePagerAct extends AppCompatActivity implements ImageFag.OnimageUrlPass{}
```

**In Activity Implements method**

```
@Override
public void getUrllist(ArrayList<ImageUrl> url) {
    this.imageUrl=url;
}
```

**error**

```
   java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.user.newsweats.UI.MainAct cannot be cast to com.example.user.newsweats.frag.ImageFag$OnimageUrlPass
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two different ways to send data from activity to fragment.
Pass data as the argument when you create using the factory method.

### Through factory method:

```
public static SimpleFragment getInstance(Bundle bundle) {
    SimpleFragment simpleFragment = new SimpleFragment();
    simpleFragment.setArguments(bundle)
    return simpleFragment;
}
```

Through this method you can pass simple objects like string.

Still, you can pass some complex objects by converting that object into parseable.

```
     new Bundle().putParcelable("Key", ParcebleObject);
```

### Through the interface

Using interface, you can pass almost any data.
Create an interface, in my case I create an interface called SomeEventListener.

> Interface

```
public interface SomeEventListener {
   public onSomeEventHappened(ArrayList<String> arrayListOfString);
}
```

> Fragment class

```
public class SimpleFragment extends Fragment implement SomeEventHappened {
    public interface onSomeEventListener {

    private ArrayList<String> arrayList;


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
       Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, null);

      //..........
      return v;
    }

   public onSomeEventHappened(ArrayList<String> arrayListOfString) {
   this.arrayList = arrayListOfString;
   }
 }
```

> In your MainActivity.java file

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      //........
      ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>();
      SimpleFragment fragment = new SimpleFragment();
      SomeEventListener listener = fragment.getEventListener();
      listener.onSomeEventHappened(array);
 }
```

This will work for any kind of object.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you put wrong `Context` object to your `RecyclerViewAdapter` constructor. Thats why object returned by `getContext` never could be cast to `OnimageUrlPass` interface. Try to call adapter constructor inside `ImagePagerAct` with `new RecyclerViewAdapter(this)`.